# Question about Showing closed sets using the closed set formulation of topology

Tags: general-topology

I am trying to show that the set $B^2= \{x^2+y^2 \leq 1\}$ is closed via the closed set formulation of continuity.

I think the book means that if $f:X \rightarrow Y$ then if V is closed in Y then $f^{-1}(V)$ is closed.

What I think I must do is define a function f in x,y such that maps a closed set to the unit circle. So I guess something say like $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2-1$ where x,y $\in [0,1]$. Is this on the right track?

Comment: There are many definitions of _closed set_, perhaps you could list what definition you are dealing with, and/or what book (e.g., Munkres?)

Comment: Yes Munkers, and the def is that A is closed if its compliment is open

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is close to it.

If $f: (x,y) \mapsto x^{2}+y^{2}: \Bbb{R}^{2} \to \mathbb{R}$, then $f$ is continuous and $B^{2} = f^{(-1)}[0, 1]$; hence $B^{2}$ is closed in $\Bbb{R}^{2}$.